# AVAssetExportSession not exporting time range

Tags: ios, audio, trim, avassetexportsession

I have this problem. I'm trimming a sound file via AVAssetExportSession. I set the time range and then export asynchronously. I'm saving the output file under different name than the input file.

It works fine BUT only for the first time. When I try to trim the trimmed file, it exports it with whole duration, but CMTimeRangeShow shows right time range.

Anyone knows, what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure you're using CMTimeRangeMake correctly? You pass it a start time and a duration, NOT a start and end time.

Comment: Yes, I do it like this:
CMTime startTime = CMTimeMultiplyByFloat64(asset.duration, fromPerc);

CMTime stopTime = CMTimeMultiplyByFloat64(asset.duration, toPerc);

CMTimeRange exportTimeRange = CMTimeRangeFromTimeToTime(startTime, stopTime);

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure my code is available for you right now because it worked on iOS7. I hope this will help you.

```
- (BOOL)trimAudio :(NSURL *) url
{
    float vocalStartMarker = timeFrom;
    float vocalEndMarker = timeTo;
    NSURL *audioFileInput = url_Audio;
    NSURL *audioFileOutput = url;

    if (!audioFileInput || !audioFileOutput)
    {
        return NO;
    }

    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtURL:audioFileOutput error:NULL];
    AVAsset *asset = [AVAsset assetWithURL:audioFileInput];

    AVAssetExportSession *exportSession = [AVAssetExportSession exportSessionWithAsset:asset
                                                                            presetName:AVAssetExportPresetAppleM4A];

    if (exportSession == nil)
    {
        return NO;
    }

    CMTime startTime = CMTimeMake((int)(floor(vocalStartMarker * 100)), 100);
    CMTime stopTime = CMTimeMake((int)(ceil(vocalEndMarker * 100)), 100);
    CMTimeRange exportTimeRange = CMTimeRangeFromTimeToTime(startTime, stopTime);

    exportSession.outputURL = audioFileOutput;
    exportSession.outputFileType = AVFileTypeAppleM4A;
    exportSession.timeRange = exportTimeRange;

    [exportSession exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^
     {
         if (AVAssetExportSessionStatusCompleted == exportSession.status)
         {
             // It worked!
         }
         else if (AVAssetExportSessionStatusFailed == exportSession.status)
         {
             // It failed...
             [[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Unknown Error" message:nil delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil]show];
         }
     }];

    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should check if the output file already exists.

"exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler" does not overwrite outputfile.

Answer (score 0):

Check the export session's `state` and `error` info within `exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler`, make sure the output URL file not exists.

Refer to these two threads, good luck!

[Unable to trim a video using AVAssetExportSession](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13097507/1677041)

[Creating a time range for AVAssetExportSession](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10773346/1677041)